# Bring namedtuple's __str__ and __repr__ behavior to regular classes

Tags: python, namedtuple, repr

https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-ideas/2014-September/029310.html

I always thought `namedtuple` builtin `__str__` and `__repr__` were very neat and I'm looking for a simple way to apply it to any classes of mine easily.

```
>>> from collections import namedtuple
>>> A  = namedtuple("A", ["foo"])
>>> print(A(foo=1))
A(foo=1)
>>> str(A(foo=1))
'A(foo=1)'
>>> repr(A(foo=1))
'A(foo=1)'
```

**EDIT:**

I initially started with a bunch of lengthy, not dynamic, hardcoded `__repr__`. I don't like that. `namedtuple` does it fancy and automatically.

```
def __repr__(self):
    return 'className(attrA={attrA}, attrB={attrB})'.format(**vars(self)))
```

Comment: You can see how namedtuple is implemented: https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Lib/collections.py#l247

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A bit hacky but this does it:

```
from collections import namedtuple

def nice_repr(obj):
    def nice_repr(self):
        return repr(
            namedtuple(
                type(self).__name__,
                vars(self)
            )(**vars(self))
        )

    obj.__repr__ = nice_repr

    return obj
```

Example:

```
@nice_repr
class A:
    def __init__(self, b, c):
        self.b = b
        self.c = c

print(repr(A(1, 2)))  # Outputs: A(c=2, b=1)
```

**EDIT:** (Fail-safe version)

```
def nice_repr(obj):
    """ Decorator to bring namedtuple's __repr__ behavior to regular classes. """

    def nice_repr(self):
        v = vars(self)

        # Prevent infinite looping if `vars` happens to include `self`.
        del(v['self'])

        return repr(namedtuple(type(self).__name__, v)(**v))

    obj.__repr__ = nice_repr

    return obj
```

Comment: Actually it is tooo much hacky and is not the worth for such a trivial thing. Declaration of `__repr__` and `__str__` function in your class was all you needed

Comment: @MoinuddinQuadri And copy/paste it every time manually? Meh… I'll pass. Or hardcode it, meh too!

Comment: This repr implementation makes some sense for `namedtuple` (which is immutable and can satisfy the usual invariant that `eval(repr(a)) == a`).  But how often do you need to define a custom class that is just a bunch of attributes?  We have already data structures for most of those use-cases.

Comment: Creating a namedtuple class just to get a string representation of an instance is a little bit too much imo, it's easy enough to format a string of the form "name(foo=1, bar=2)" if you already have the name and the vars. But +1 for creativity :-)

Comment: importing an additional library and creating a `namedtuple` object each time just to display the string is not the correct way in my opinion

Comment: I just don't think it's a good idea in the first place.  Consider if an instance has an attribute is a blob of json or something, you can end up with a repr which is thousands of lines long, and totally bollocks up the logging in your app - consuming all disk space, for example.  Your implementation "works" ok, but remember: just because you *can*, doesn't mean you *should*.  repr is not intended to be human readable.

Comment: @wim Oh I know… it wouldn't be something I use everywhere. It is hacky. If I were to make it customizable/safe, it would start getting dirtier for not much interesting value added.

Comment: whats up with your indentation in your return statement ??

Comment: @0TTT0 In the first code? It was to avoid to put all on one line as I did in the other example. It's still perfectly valid. I tried making it more "readable" but I'm not sure it's a success or not. I don't see anything else wrong or particular with the others `return`s I used.

Comment: it is valid.  in general i think its more readable to keep your code on one line, unless its a nested list comp / genexp or goes over 80 characters

Answer (score 2):

If I were you, I would have created a Parent Class with the definition of `__repr__` method and inherit that class in the child classes to have that behavior. To me, [your solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41600946/2063361) looks like a huge hack in order to achieve very trivial thing. Below is the sample:

```
class BaseClass:

     # logic can be used with in `__repr__` itself.
     # creating separate function to make it more clear
     def _get_formatted_string(self):
         return '{class_name}({params})'.format(
             class_name=self.__class__.__name__,
             params=', '.join('{}={}'.format(k, v) for k, v in vars(self).items()))

     def __repr__(self):
         return self._get_formatted_string()

class child(BaseClass):

    def __init__(self, a, b):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
```

Here is the desired behavior:

```
>>> c = child(1, 2)
>>> repr(c)
'child(a=1, b=2)'
>>> str(c)
'child(a=1, b=2)'
```

Answer (score 2):

**typing.NamedTuple is new and elegant**. A better version of collections.namedtuple.

```py
from typing import NamedTuple

class Employee(NamedTuple):
    name: str
    id: int
```

is basically the same as

```py
Employee = collections.namedtuple('Employee', ['name', 'id'])
```

A more advanced example for this question

```py
from typing imoprt NamedTuple

class Employee(NamedTuple):
    """Represents an employee."""
    name: str
    id: int = 3

    def __repr__(self) -> str:
        return f'<Employee {self.name}, id={self.id}>'
```

see https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.NamedTuple

Answer (score -1):

when you create any class you define your own `__str__` function just like you create an `__init__` function

```
class Foo:
    def __init__(self):
        self.a="value"

    def __str__(self):
        return "a is: "+self.a

variable=Foo()
print variable
```

this will print: "a is: value" 
you can do this for any class

Comment: Defeats the purpose. I'd like not having to hardcode it and have a fancy `repr` like the `namedtuple` one.

Comment: @JeromeJ you can make it anything you want. if you want to build it from something in the class you can do that too

Comment: I started with a bunch of lengthy `def __repr__(self): \ return 'className(attrA={attrA}, attrB={attrB})'.format(**self))` which is annoying and not dynamic. No thanks.

Comment: I'm not looking for flexibility here. I know I can define `__str__` and `__repr__` directly in the class itself. It isn't what I'm looking for.